# Visit without pageview in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Today I saw some metrics on one of my websites in Google Analytics and found something strange to me.

How can I get visits without pageviews?

I looked at Audience>Engagement>Page Depth
I have page depth<1 and 710 visits

Is there a problem in these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at your Traffic Sources to see which sources are generating the Visits? I would assume since they are visiting less than 1 page it is bots hitting your site which aren't doing anything.

You should have a page view each time a page is loaded unless the time on site is so little the javascript isn't loading entirely or the bots aren't triggering a page view at all but some how a visit is counted

When visitors return within 30 minutes Google counts them as the same visitor not as a unique.

Comment: Does google track my js part of website without setting virtual pageviews in google analytics? or I need first setting virtual pageviews in google analytics for google can track and count that in my total bounce rate, pages per session ... ?